# Setup SD card so Pi-Zero-W looks for WPS WiFo connection

Tags: pi-zero-w

I've done some googling on the topic of the zero and WPS but most of them talk about running some commands on the zero to get it to connect WPS.

The problem I am trying to solve is....   I can't run any commands until it connects to the network so that I can SSH into it.

Has anyone found any edits to the SD download file that can enable WPS on first boot?

Kind of like how you create a .ssh file to enable ssh and how you can pre-edit the wpa_supplicant file to enter your wifi credentials?

In an ideal world, any time the zero is NOT on active wifi then it will somehow try to WPS.

Ideas?

I'm doing an IOT for something and if I take the zero to another location I can't easily get it to connect to the new wifi unless I manually edit the supplicant to add the new wifi before I leave my home.

Comment: No idea if this works on Buster (it did on Stretch based on the last post) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=77277 - feel free to answer your own question if it does :-)